# Do subst drives behave differently on windows 10?

Tags: winapi, windows-10

I am debugging a problem where the functionality seems to have changed in Windows 10. If I have a subst drive (ex: `subst t:\ c:\my-very-long-path`). When I launch from the mapped drive (`t:\myapp.exe`), `::GetModuleFileNameEx(::GetCurrentProcess(), ...)` returns the initial path (`c:\my-very-long-path\myapp.exe`).

Is this an explicit change in `subst`? A change in `GetModuleFileNameEx`?

This seems inconsistent with `GetCurrentDirectory` which returns the mapped directory (`t:\`).

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but why are you calling [GetModuleFileNameEx](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683198.aspx) with a handle to the current process instead of [GetModuleFileName](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683197.aspx)?

Comment: I can reproduce the change in behaviour.  The way that `subst` works doesn't seem to have changed, so I would guess at a change in `GetModuleFileNameEx`.  I note that `GetModuleFileName` does *not* exhibit this new behaviour, so that may be a workaround in some cases.